# Combinatorial optimization with discrete options in R

Tags: r, optimization, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem, particle-swarm

I have a function with five variables that I want to maximize using only an specific set of parameters for each variable.

Are there any methods in R that can do this, other than by brutal force? (e.g. Particle Swarm Optimization, Genetic Algorithm, Greedy, etc.). I have read a few packages but they seem to create their own set of parameters from within a given range. I am only interested in optimizing the set of options provided.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
#Example of 5 variable function to optimize
Fn<-function(x){
  a=x[1]
  b=x[2]
  c=x[3]
  d=x[4]
  e=x[5]
  SUM=a+b+c+d+e
 return(SUM)
}

#Parameters for variables to optimize
Vars=list(
  As=c(seq(1.5,3, by = 0.3)),             #float
  Bs=c(1,2),                              #Binary
  Cs=c(seq(1,60, by=10)),                  #Integer
  Ds=c(seq(60,-60, length.out=5)),        #Negtive
  Es=c(1,2,3)
)

#Full combination
FullCombn= expand.grid(Vars)

Results=data.frame(I=as.numeric(),   Sum=as.numeric())
for (i in 1:nrow(FullCombn)){
  ParsI=FullCombn[i,]
  ResultI=Fn(ParsI)
  Results=rbind(Results,c(I=i,Sum=ResultI))
}

#Best iteration (Largest result)
Best=Results[Results[, 2] == max(Results[, 2]),]
#Best parameters
FullCombn[Best$I,]
```

Comment: you don't have any constraint that involves combination of variables. To maximize sum just pick maximum value for each variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a genetic algorithm solution with package `GA`.
The key is to write a function `decode` enforcing the constraints, see the package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/vignettes/GA.html).

```r
library(GA)
#> Loading required package: foreach
#> Loading required package: iterators
#> Package 'GA' version 3.2.2
#> Type 'citation("GA")' for citing this R package in publications.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'GA'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     de

decode <- function(x) {
  As <- Vars$As
  Bs <- Vars$Bs
  Cs <- Vars$Cs
  Ds <- rev(Vars$Ds)
  # fix real variable As
  i <- findInterval(x[1], As)
  if(x[1L] - As[i] < As[i + 1L] - x[1L])
    x[1L] <- As[i]
  else x[1L] <- As[i + 1L]
  # fix binary variable Bs
  if(x[2L] - Bs[1L] < Bs[2L] - x[2L])
    x[2L] <- Bs[1L]
  else x[2L] <- Bs[2L]
  # fix integer variable Cs
  i <- findInterval(x[3L], Cs)
  if(x[3L] - Cs[i] < Cs[i + 1L] - x[3L])
    x[3L] <- Cs[i]
  else x[3L] <- Cs[i + 1L]
  # fix integer variable Ds
  i <- findInterval(x[4L], Ds)
  if(x[4L] - Ds[i] < Ds[i + 1L] - x[4L])
    x[4L] <- Ds[i]
  else x[4L] <- Ds[i + 1L]
  # fix the other, integer variable
  x[5L] <- round(x[5L])
  setNames(x  , c("As", "Bs", "Cs", "Ds", "Es"))
}
Fn <- function(x){
  x <- decode(x)
  # a <- x[1]
  # b <- x[2]
  # c <- x[3]
  # d <- x[4]
  # e <- x[5]
  # SUM <- a + b + c + d + e
  SUM <- sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  return(SUM)
}

#Parameters for variables to optimize
Vars <- list(
  As = seq(1.5, 3, by = 0.3),              # Float
  Bs = c(1, 2),                            # Binary
  Cs = seq(1, 60, by = 10),                # Integer
  Ds = seq(60, -60, length.out = 5),       # Negative
  Es = c(1, 2, 3)
)

res <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
          fitness = Fn, 
          lower = c(1.5, 1, 1, -60, 1),
          upper = c(3, 2, 51, 60, 3),
          popSize = 1000,
          seed = 123)
summary(res)
#> ── Genetic Algorithm ─────────────────── 
#> 
#> GA settings: 
#> Type                  =  real-valued 
#> Population size       =  1000 
#> Number of generations =  100 
#> Elitism               =  50 
#> Crossover probability =  0.8 
#> Mutation probability  =  0.1 
#> Search domain = 
#>        x1 x2 x3  x4 x5
#> lower 1.5  1  1 -60  1
#> upper 3.0  2 51  60  3
#> 
#> GA results: 
#> Iterations             = 100 
#> Fitness function value = 119 
#> Solutions = 
#>             x1       x2       x3       x4       x5
#> [1,]  2.854089 1.556080 46.11389 49.31045 2.532682
#> [2,]  2.869408 1.638266 46.12966 48.71106 2.559620
#> [3,]  2.865254 1.665405 46.21684 49.04667 2.528606
#> [4,]  2.866494 1.630416 46.12736 48.78017 2.530454
#> [5,]  2.860940 1.650015 46.31773 48.92642 2.521276
#> [6,]  2.851644 1.660358 46.09504 48.81425 2.525504
#> [7,]  2.855078 1.611837 46.13855 48.62022 2.575492
#> [8,]  2.857066 1.588893 46.15918 48.60505 2.588992
#> [9,]  2.862644 1.637806 46.20663 48.92781 2.579260
#> [10,] 2.861573 1.630762 46.23494 48.90927 2.555612
#>  ...                                              
#> [59,] 2.853788 1.640810 46.35649 48.87381 2.536682
#> [60,] 2.859090 1.658127 46.15508 48.85404 2.590679
apply(res@solution, 1, decode) |> t() |> unique()
#>      As Bs Cs Ds Es
#> [1,]  3  2 51 60  3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Among the set of solutions yielded by ga, many are not among the possibilities provided. Does the decode function requires better constraints to use exactly the values provided?

Comment: @Camilo You are right, I hadn't noticed the case of the `Ds`. Give me a moment. The others are right or have I missed something else?

Comment: @Camilo Done, see now.

Answer (score 1):

Two more possibilities. Both minimize by default, so I flip the sign in your objective function (i.e. return `-SUM`).

```
#Example of 5 variable function to optimize
Fn<-function(x, ...){
  a=x[1]
  b=x[2]
  c=x[3]
  d=x[4]
  e=x[5]
  SUM=a+b+c+d+e
 return(-SUM)
}

#Parameters for variables to optimize
Vars=list(
  As=c(seq(1.5,3, by = 0.3)),             #float
  Bs=c(1,2),                              #Binary
  Cs=c(seq(1,60, by=10)),                 #Integer
  Ds=c(seq(60,-60, length.out=5)),        #Negtive
  Es=c(1,2,3)
)
```

First, a grid search. Exactly what you did, just convenient.  And the implementation allows you to distribute the evaluations of the objective function.

```
library("NMOF")
gridSearch(fun = Fn,
           levels = Vars)[c("minfun", "minlevels")]


## 5 variables with 6, 2, 6, 5, ... levels: 1080 function evaluations required.
## $minfun
## [1] -119
## 
## $minlevels
## [1]  3  2 51 60  3
```

An alternative: a simple Local Search. You start with a valid initial guess, and then move randomly through possible feasible solutions. The key ingredient is the neighbourhood function. It picks one element randomly and then, again randomly, sets this element to one allowed value.

```
nb <- function(x, levels, ...) {
    i <- sample(length(levels), 1)
    x[i] <- sample(levels[[i]], 1)
    x
}
```

(There would be better algorithms for neighbourhood functions; but this one is simple and so demonstrates the idea well.)

```
LSopt(Fn, list(x0 = c(1.8, 2, 11, 30, 2),  ## a feasible initial solution
               neighbour = nb,             
               nI = 200                    ## iterations
               ),
      levels = Vars)$xbest
## Local Search.
## ##...
## Best solution overall: -119
## [1]  3  2 51 60  3
```

(Disclosure: I am the maintainer of package [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF), which provides functions `gridSearch` and `LSopt`.)

---

In response to the comment, a few remarks on Local Search and the neighbourhood function above (`nb`). Local Search, as implemented in
`LSopt`, will start with an arbitrary solution, and
then change that solution slightly. This new solution,
called a neighbour, will be compared (by its
objective-function value) to the old solution. If the new solution is
better, it becomes the current solution; otherwise it
is rejected and the old solution remains the current one.
Then the algorithm repeats, for a number of iterations.
So, in short, Local Search is not random sampling, but
a guided random-walk through the search space. It's
guided because only better solutions get accepted, worse one's get rejected. In this sense, `LSopt` will narrow down on good parameter values.

The implementation of the neighbourhood is not ideal
for two reasons.  The first is that a solution may not
be changed at all, since I sample from feasible
values. But for a small set of possible values as here,
it might often happen that the same element is selected
again.  However, for larger search spaces, this
inefficiency is typically negligible, since the
probability of sampling the same value becomes
smaller. Often so small, that the additional code for
testing if the solution has changed becomes more
expensive that the occasionally-wasted iteration.

A second thing could be improved, albeit through a more
complicated function. And again, for this small problem it does not matter. In the current neighbourhood, an
element is picked and then set to any feasible value.
But that means that changes from one solution to the
next might be large.  Instead of picking any feasible values of the `As`,
in realistic problems it will often be better to pick a
value close to the current value. For example, when you are at 2.1, either move to 1.8 or 2.4, but not to 3.0. (This reasoning is only relevant, of course, if the variable in question is on a numeric or at least ordinal scale.)

Ultimately, what implementation works well can be
tested only empirically. Many more details are in this [tutorial](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756).

Here is one alternative implementation. A solution is now a vector of positions for the original values, e.g. if `x[1]` is 2, it "points" to 1.8, if `x[2]` is 2, it points to 1, and so on.

```
## precompute lengths of vectors in Vars
lens <- lengths(Vars)

nb2 <- function(x, lens, ...) {
    i <- sample(length(lens), 1)
    if (x[i] == 1L) {
        x[i] <- 2
    } else if (x[i] == lens[i]) {
        x[i] <- lens[i] - 1
    } else
        x[i] <- x[i] + sample(c(1, -1), 1)
    x
}


## the objective function now needs to map the
## indices in x back to the levels in Vars
Fn2 <- function(x, levels, ...){

    y <- mapply(`[`, levels, x)
    ## => same as
    ##      y <- numeric(length(x))
    ##      y[1] <- Vars[[1]][x[1]]
    ##      y[2] <- Vars[[2]][x[2]]
    ##      ....

    SUM <- sum(y)
    return(-SUM)
}

xbest <- LSopt(Fn2,
               list(x0 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),    ## an initial solution
                    neighbour = nb2,
                    nI = 200                  ## iterations
                    ),
               levels = Vars,
               lens = lens)$xbest
## Local Search.
## ....
## Best solution overall: -119

## map the solution back to the values
mapply(`[`, Vars, xbest)
## As Bs Cs Ds Es 
##  3  2 51 60  3
```

Comment: Why are our solutions different? Intuitively, since the objective function is a sum, it is maximized for the maxima of its arguments.

Comment: @RuiBarradas My first guess would have been "stochastics" `:-)` but the GA solution seems to include values that are not allowed (I think): `C` is 60 in your GA code, but must be in `1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51`.

Comment: You're right, thanks, after the edit the solutions are identical. I hadn't noticed that `max(Cs) == 51`, I saw the `seq` statement and assumed it was the `to` argument. :(

Comment: @EnricoSchumann thanks for your response.... when you say that there may be a better neighborhood function...is there any lead I can follow...that function already works as expected....also does the LSopt function narrows in within the spectrum of the best solution at a given time...or it keeps trying over the full set of options?

Comment: @Camilo I have added some explanations.